# How to Write into XML using AJAX / Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

i am makin an editor for CMS . now i want to create an XML file and i wnt to write content into XML file

Comment: You can't do that using only JavaScript. You have to pass the XML file e.g. as a string to e.g. a PHP script. //I assumed that you want to create a XML file on a server... Right?

Comment: No i am not using PHP . I am using only javascript and Ajax . so is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can handle XML very well, actually Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) was at first meant to deal with ajax only later plain text prevailed.

You can use the following functions to handle XML

**Convert XML node to string**

```
function XMLToStr(xmlNode){
    try{ // Mozilla, Webkit, Opera
        return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlNode);
    }catch(E) {
        try {  // IE
            return xmlNode.xml;
        }catch(E2){}
    }
}
```

**Convert a String to XML object**

```
function strToXML(xmlString){
    var dom_parser = ("DOMParser" in window && (new DOMParser()).parseFromString) ||
          (window.ActiveXObject && function(_xmlString) {
            var xml_doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            xml_doc.async = 'false';
            xml_doc.loadXML(_xmlString);
            return xml_doc;
        });
    if(!dom_parser){
        return false;
    }
    return dom_parser.call("DOMParser" in window && (new DOMParser()) || window, xmlString, 'text/xml');
}
```

**Usage:**

Convert a string into XML node and fetch some values from it

```
var xml = strToXML('<root><name>abc</name></root>');
console.log(xml.firstChild.nodeName); // root
console.log(xml.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue); // abc
```

To load XML object from an Ajax call instead of plain text or JSON, use `responseXML` instead of `responseText` - the only caveat being that the XML needs to be correctly sent from the server, ie. the content-type needs to be correct and the XML must be valid.